# jbosgi 2.3.0 download links seems to be broken

Tags: java, osgi, wildfly-8, application-server

Please, i'm interested in finding a link to download jbosgi at 2.3.0.Final. I've no experience using osgi and i read a post here that explain the integration with Wildfly 8.2.0 but the links they are suggesting are always broken.

What i'm trying to do is enabling osgi inside wildfly 8.2.0 (or any other application server), but i need the specific version of jbosgi (2.3.0.Final) and i think that this is the way.

So, i need a link to download the installer of jbossgi 2.3.0.Final. Please if someone helps me would be grateful.

Any other suggestions or advises about others app servers will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: This question is better asked of JBoss directly.

Comment: The 2.3.0 release you're referring to was a fork of the original jbosgi projects and was maintained by a single person. It looks like they've abandoned it and remove it from git (those links worked earlier in the year). If you're trying to get into OSGi that project probably isn't the best place to start.